# How to integrate $\int\frac{-(x+1)}{(x^2)\sqrt{x^2+10x+5}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int\frac{-(x+1)}{(x^2)\sqrt{x^2+10x+5}}dx?$$
I tried with different substitutions, i.e. $x+1=\frac{1}{t}$, but I am not getting the answer.

Comment: [Euler's substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) rationalize all problems of that "type". In your case, it could be $\sqrt{x^2+10x+5}=-x+t$.

Comment: $\int\frac{-(x+1)}{(x^2)\sqrt{x^2+10x+5}}dx
\overset{t=1/x}= \int\frac{1+t}{\sqrt{1+10t+5t^2}}dt
=\frac15 \sqrt{1+10t+5t^2}
$

Comment: As @Quanto points out, whenever you see a $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$ in your integrand it's a good idea to try a substitution of the form $t =\frac{1}{x} + c$ for some constant $c$ since its differential is (up to a sign change) exactly $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$, so you will likely get a nice simplification.